# Orientability of space with only even dimensional cells.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have the following question:

> Suppose a compact $\mathbb{R}$-manifold has finite cell decomposition with only even dimensional cells. Then $M$ is orientable.

It's a theorem that a closed connected $n$ manifold is orientable iff its top homology group $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$.

The cell complex looks something like
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}^{k_n}\to 0\to\cdots
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}^{k_n}$ is the degree $n$-chain group, if there are $k_n$ $n$-cells in $M$. Clearly $H_n(M)=\mathbb{Z}^{k_n}$.

I think the question is ambiguous, and there is the implicit assumption that there is just one cell in each even dimension? Moreover, it seems sufficient that there be a unique cell of highest degree, and no cells of degree one lesser for a manifold to be orientable.

Is this question poorly written, or am I interpreting it wrong?, because my interpretation makes it seem trivial.

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is connected? If so, what are the possible $H_n(M)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Nope, there's no assumption that $M$ is connected. If it were, does duality imply $H_n(M)=H^0(M)$, which is $1$-dimensional?

Comment: Hint: show that $H_1(M)=0$ and, hence, the fundamental group cannot have nontrivial homomorphisms to $Z/2$.

Comment: @studiosus Thanks, is this right: $H_1(M)=0$ since there are no $1$-cells, since this is the abelianization of $\pi_1(M)$, $\pi_1(M)$ is equal to its commutator subgroup, so generated by commutators. The homomorphic image of any commutator into an abelian group is the identity, so $\pi_1(M)$ has no nontrivial homomorphisms into $Z/2$. But $M$ is orientable if $\pi_1(M)$ has no subgroup of index $2$. This is certainly the case, for if $H\leq\pi_1(M)$ where such a subgroup, the canonical projection $\pi_1(M)\to\pi_1(M)/H\cong\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ would be nontrivial.

Comment: That is right...

Comment: Pudnik, no, Poincaré duality assumes orientability. But it's standard that a compact $n$-manifold (without boundary) has $H_n(M)\cong\Bbb Z$ if it's orientable and $H_n(M)\cong 0$ if not.